# Primefaces tabview does not include all tabs

Tags: primefaces

I have a primefaces tabview with a variable count of dynamic tabs on the left side. Each tab may contain elements which make a tab varies from height.

When the number of tabs is large, and the content of the selected tab is short, the tab titles are beyond the confines of the tabview. The whole page can not be scrolled to access lower tabs. So in such cases, there is no way to select the bottom tabs that are down below the bottom of the page.

Is there any way to make the tabview enclose all the tabs?

```
                        <p:tabView orientation="left" style="width: 100%; padding: 5px;" value="#{clientEncounterComponentFormController.findClientEncounterComponentFormOfAFormset(clientEncounterComponentFormSetController.selected)}" var="f">
                            <p:tab title="#{f.name}" >
                                <div style="#{f.generatedCss}" >
                                    <ez:clinicForms form="#{f}" ></ez:clinicForms>
                                </div>
                            </p:tab>
                        </p:tabView>
```

[image: Bottom tabes are outside tabview]

Comment: Tried playing with css height etc?

Comment: Height should vary with dynamic content.

Comment: So? I nowhere said it should get a number as (fixed) value, and the 'etc' means you should investigste more css. Your question does not show any attempt. Nor does it show a [mcve]. Might be that other code limits things

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your code, so thats hard for me to answer you correctly.

1) TabView component is not for a big content with long text, I would like to recommend you [SelectOneMenu](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml) or [MultiSelectListbox](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/multiSelectListbox.xhtml), thats really better for working with a lot of options.

2) Also you can change size of tabs dynamically by css, you are able to set styles by conditions like:

```
<p:tabview value="#{yourBean.listOfObjects}" style="height: 5vw;" rendered="yourBean.isThereBigContent()">
</p:tabview>

<p:tabview value="#{yourBean.listOfObjects}" style="height: 10vw;" rendered="!yourBean.isThereBigContent()">
</p:tabview>
```

Bean:

```
public boolean isThereBigContent() {
  return this.listOfObjects.size() > 8;
```

}

Comment: I have added the code. The number of tabes can vary depending on the dynamic content. All I need to have a minimum height of tab view to include all tabs.

Comment: Ok and what is in generatedCss? Whats wrong, how much tabs do you have? Could you set the height to lower px? Just add style="height=4px;" to p:tab